# Do you know why stack view in scroll view doesn't fit on simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

hello every one basically I want to fit stack view in scroll view in my Xcode design it's ok , and I have not an error but unfortunately in simulator really different about design , and here is my stack view and scroll view constraints and also I bring the result in simulator :

[image]

and also this is my one of content constraints that all of view like this are horizontally and vertically in container alignment :

[image]

could you tel me what's your opinion to solve this matter?

Comment: What about each content constraint?

Comment: @setonugroho  inside of each views I set horizontally and vertically container content of each view

Comment: Your scroll view can't calculate it's vertical content size. Judging by your design it seems like you can overcome this by setting a height constraint for each row of the stack view.

Comment: Also you should use content layout guides in your scroll view to enable frame and content layout guides. That should make it easier to handle the content.

Comment: @Desdenova maybe you are right ,  for set a height constraint for each row should I use attributes inspector of my stack view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the each content is piling up like the result in simulator is because scroll view unable to calculate content height and also each content constraint has the center point set up to be the same as another (or the same as stack center)

What you can do to fix the UI is

1. Set the first content top constraint to stack view top
2. Set the next content top constraint to last item bottom
3. Set the last item bottom constraint to stack view bottom
4. Set each item height and width

So in summary, each view should have this constraint:

1. top constraint equal (or add some margin) to previous view bottom constraint, except for first view where it should be equal to stack view top
2. bottom constraint equal (or add some margin) to next view top constraint, except for last view where it should be equal to stack view bottom
3. height constraint
4. width constraint
5. remove center x and y constraint

That way scroll view can calculate its content height

Comment: thanks brother for your answer , your mean I should set new constrains to each of view in stack view? because I try this but have not the result that I want it.

Comment: yes, each view should be able to position themselves inside the stack view by giving them sufficient constraint. What constraints that you added?

Comment: for example I add View.top = top this constraint to my first view and for second view I add this View.top = View.bottom , and also repeat for each item

Comment: i assume you add it as View1.top = stackView.top, View2.top = View1.bottom, etc. Have you add height constraint to each item? do they have dynamic height?

Comment: no how can I add dynamic height for each view?

Comment: what i mean by dynamic height is that the height of view cannot be calculated before runtime. If you don't have any, then you should set height constraint to each view

Comment: thank you so much brother , now I have the result that I want, I'm very proud of you, to put your time kindly and define it to me